# Change color of point on mouse click and back to original on release

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, shader, opengl-3

I am working on an OpenGL code using shaders where one of the requirements is to change the color of a point to white (or anything) on a mouse click and change it back to its original color once released. Is there any function that can retrieve the vertices of the point being clicked and change its color? There are eight points that form a circle whose vertices are

*(0,√2), (1,1), (√2, 0), (1,-1), (0,-√2), (-1,-1), (-√2,0), (-1,1)* (basically a circle with a radius of √2 units)

I have initially defined the points as given below

```
Vertex Vertices[] =
{
    { { 0.0f, 1.414214f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 0
    { { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 1
    { { -1.414214f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 2
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 3
    { { 0.0f, -1.414214f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 4
    { { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 5
    { { 1.414214f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 6
    { { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 7

};
```

Comment: No, there is no such function. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: @immibis Thank you